# In a Django project, given a Page and a Reading model, how do I create a functionality for the user to click on words to select and save them?

Tags: javascript, python, django

In a Django project, I have a Page model (fields = ['book', 'page_number', 'text']) and a Reading model (fields = ['group', 'pages', 'due_date']).
How can we display the text of these pages so that when we click on a word, that word gets added to a dictionary of words with the key being the word and the values being the page_number where the word is and the word's starting index?
I don't know what's the right combination of model, form, view, and JavaScript script to get this done.

The following is basically the extent of my knowledge. So that's why I'm stuck.

model.py

```
class ReadingPerformance(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reading = models.ForeignKey('Reading', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mistakes = models.JSONField() # First time using this, not sure what it does.

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.student}  {self.reading}"
```

form.py:

```
class ReadingPerformanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReadingPerformance
        fields = ['student', 'reading', 'mistakes']
```

view.py:

```
def add_reading_performance(request):
    form = ReadingPerformanceForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReadingPerformanceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('reading_performance_list')
    return render(request, 'add_reading_performance.html', {'form': form})

def reading_performance_list(request):
    reading_performances = ReadingPerformance.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'reading_performance_list.html', {'reading_performances': reading_performances})
```

add_reading_performance.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Add a new reading performance</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```